# Python, modified version of one hot encoder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help to convert unique values from multiple columns, for example columns a1 and a2, into new columns, then assign values  from columns b1 and b2 to those newly created columns accordingly.

For example, if I have a data frame df as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1':['q','w','e','r'], 'a2':['s','e','q','u'], 'b1':[1,2,3,4], 'b2':[5,6,7,8],})

print(df)
```

> ```
>   a1 a2  b1  b2
> 0  q  s   1   5
> 1  w  e   2   6
> 2  e  q   3   7
> 3  r  u   4   8
> ```

The unique values of columns a1 and a2 are ['e', 'q', 'r', 's', 'u', 'w'].

```
np.unique(df.loc[:,['a1','a2']].values)
```

> ```
> array(['e', 'q', 'r', 's', 'u', 'w'], dtype=object)
> ```

I would like to convert df to a new data frame df1 as below:

```
print(df1)
```

> ```
>    e  q  r  s  u  w
> 0  0  1  0  5  0  0
> 1  6  0  0  0  0  2
> 2  3  7  0  0  0  0
> 3  0  0  4  0  8  0
> ```

Note that 'q' and 's' appears in the first row of df, thus 1 (from column b1) and 5 (from column b2) are assigned to q and s columns of a dataframe df1 while other columns are 0.

I could have used melt and dcast functions in R to achieve this, however I am not sure how to do it in Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Check version 4 in the edit history of your question. I showed you how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52232617/revisions But giving code which defines the dataframes is also very good. Nice edit.

Comment: If you edit the qestion you see the markdown used. Use it the same way for different numbers and letters and you will have the same outcome. I do not see your problem. Reading up on formatting on StackOverflow will make you aware that the four blanks at the start of each line of what I made are what causes the paragraph to be considered code, which changes the way it is shown. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: done, thanks for helping me to improve my post layout

Comment: My pleasure. But don't overdo the formatting. Use only code formatting for code, not also block quoting.

Comment: Are you looking solution in `r` that you tagged it?

Comment: sorry, I am looking for a solution in python, I have removed "r" now

Comment: What if column a1 and column a2 have the same value ? Say `["q", "q"] `for the first row ?

Comment: thanks for your question, it is not possible in this case due to the nature of the data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1':['q','w','e','r'], 'a2':['s','e','q','u'], 'b1':[1,2,3,4], 'b2':[5,6,7,8],})
pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dict(zip(df.iloc[t,:2] , df.iloc[t,2:])) for t in range(len(df))]).fillna(0).astype(int)
    e   q   r   s   u   w
0   0   1   0   5   0   0
1   6   0   0   0   0   2
2   3   7   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   4   0   8   0
```